# finding distances within unique ID values (tracks) of a (huge) matrix, Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, matrix, unique, distance

I have had a search around on this, but being new to matlab I could do with more specific help with my issue.

I have a huge matrix <2182824x9double> where each row represents a particle being tracked over time with columns including (numerical) TrackID, Time, Lat and Long.

What I need to do is for each unique TrackID, take time=0 and call that the start position, and for every other row within that TrackID (where time is not 0), find the distance (as the crow flies) from the start lat long (this is in order to find the maximal distance from the start point achieved being not necessarily the end point of the track).

To further complicate this i have a non-standard radius for the earth so I need a method which will allow me to stipulate this radius (6371.001km).

I don't really know where to start on this, and am worried about computational effort given the size of my matrix (I have many more such matrices to do the same thing to) - any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Many thanks for your time and attention,
All the best,

Bex

Comment: OK, start writing the code.  Don't worry about computational time yet.  First worry about correctness.  Then you can find the computational bottlenecks and work on improving those, while verifying that the results match your known good results.  Also, working code can be shown to others (including SO) for optimization suggestions.   You say you don't know where to start.  Your problem statement is pretty clear, so start at the beginning: find the start position of each trackID.  Then go to the next step...

Comment: [*Premature optimization is the root of all evil*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) - [Donald Knuth](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonKnuth)

Comment: I agree with the above comments, but I'll add that you will have to first think about how you are going to store your output - if you need to store it? Maybe each result is saved to a file, or used for further calculation instead of being stored? What are you doing with these distances> You probably won't have enough RAM to store a 2182824*2182824 matrix (I have 16gb here and trying to initialise that gives me an out of memory error). Start working on a subset of your data, say 1000 IDs - a 1000x1000 array is easy.

Comment: The only thing you really need to know is the formula for calculating the distance between two points.  If you need help with that specifically, then you can ask that question with an "algorithms" tag.  Once you have that, this is easy, and it really isn't a very big data set.  You should probably make a cell array organized into track IDs.  One hint would be to use unique(data(:,trackIdColumn)) to find all the different trackIDs, then use find or logical indexing to pull out the data for each trackID.

Comment: Thanks all, I will follow your advice and probably be back to ask something more specific soon. But optimization later - got it! And am expecting and musing over storage issues. :S